# xp_cmdshell not working - Microsoft SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, database, security, sql-server-2000

I am trying to run xp_cmdshell on a Microsoft SQL Server 2000 database but running into problems. When I run a command using it, it just times out, even simple stuff like dir.

I did the following to make sure xp_cmdshell was enabled.

```
EXEC sp_configure ’show advanced options’, 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure ’xp_cmdshell’, 1
RECONFIGURE
```

When running EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1 I get the error message

*The configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.*

I confirmed the advanced options was enabled by running EXEC sp_configure, the output didn't even show xm_cmdshell, the entire output was:

```
affinity mask   -2147483648 2147483647  0   0
allow updates   0   1   0   0
awe enabled 0   1   0   0
c2 audit mode   0   1   0   0
cost threshold for parallelism  0   32767   5   5
Cross DB Ownership Chaining 0   1   0   0
cursor threshold    -1  2147483647  -1  -1
default full-text language  0   2147483647  1033    1033
default language    0   9999    0   0
fill factor (%) 0   100 0   0
index create memory (KB)    704 2147483647  0   0
lightweight pooling 0   1   0   0
locks   5000    2147483647  0   0
max degree of parallelism   0   32  0   0
max server memory (MB)  4   2147483647  2147483647  2147483647
max text repl size (B)  0   2147483647  65536   65536
max worker threads  32  32767   255 255
media retention 0   365 0   0
min memory per query (KB)   512 2147483647  1024    1024
min server memory (MB)  0   2147483647  0   0
nested triggers 0   1   1   1
network packet size (B) 512 32767   4096    4096
open objects    0   2147483647  0   0
priority boost  0   1   0   0
query governor cost limit   0   2147483647  0   0
query wait (s)  -1  2147483647  -1  -1
recovery interval (min) 0   32767   0   0
remote access   0   1   1   1
remote login timeout (s)    0   2147483647  20  20
remote proc trans   0   1   0   0
remote query timeout (s)    0   2147483647  600 600
scan for startup procs  0   1   0   0
set working set size    0   1   0   0
show advanced options   0   1   1   1
two digit year cutoff   1753    9999    2049    2049
user connections    0   32767   0   0
user options    0   32767   0   0
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain this option doesn't exist in SQL 2000. It was only introduced in later versions. So get back to troubleshooting your original issue about it timing out. Can you post the exact T-SQL that is timing out?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct. Did you run those two sp_configure options separately and then reconfigure as opposed to running the whole thing as a single statement?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```